# Pairwise additivity of numerical potentials

Tags: computational-physics, discrete

Surely this is a trivial problem, but I'm very much confused on how to approach so please bear with me.

Say I have a two-dimensional evenly-spaced 16x16 grid centered at the point (x1,y1). I also have two functions (F1 & F2) that only differ on where they are centered:

F1 = F(x-x1,y-y1) and F2 = F(x-x2,y-y2)

To calculate the value of F1 + F2 on the grid, I only need to plug the coordinates into the functions and add them together.

How can I calculate F1 + F2 on the grid if I can only evaluate F1? Aside from the values of F1 on the grid all I have available are the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how you could get $F1+F2$ without having $F2$.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, and if (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) both correspond to points on the grid, you could simply shift the values in a corresponding way to get F2 from F1. However, if you only have F1 tabulated on the $16\times16$ grid, the shift will leave some grid positions empty (unless your system is periodic in 2D): there's no way around this unless you can evaluate the function F, or extrapolate it somehow. And if (x2,y2) is not exactly a grid position, you'll need to adopt some kind of interpolation scheme. Can you give more details, so people can see where the difficulty lies?